# Crash report not showing up on the dashboard

Tags: report, dashboard, google-fabric

I’m integrating crashlytics into an app and forcing a crash to see if the integration is working. I see in charles the report getting uploaded (i think) but the dashboard is showing nothing.
There is no issue with dSYM’s according to the app information on the dashboard.
I sent a mail to support@fabric.io and have not got a response yet.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you let me know if you are still running into this issue? I'd love to help :)

Comment: Support responded a few days ago, i sent them debug traces, i do see a crash report now, looks like it magically started working.

I did see a crash in fabric itself 
 <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Fabric firebaseMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14464b350'

[Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
     "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.6";
     "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.9.0";
     "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.10";

Thanks for following up.